# elasticsearch: why is shard size missing in response to /_cat/shards

Tags: elasticsearch

We are seeing errors adding to the index, and when we ask for /_cat/shards we see this.

The cluster status is green, and we see no other issues so far.

What does the below mean?

[image: Response to /_cat/shards]

Answer (score 0):

OK, we see why.

We had to look in the log. (The cluster status is green, but the cluster is blown up... odd to us.)

The problem is fielddata and memory. We thought by going to nodes with %100 more memory that we would solve this, but this turns out not to be the case.

(We have code to monitor breakers, but that code has not yet deployed.)

```
[node-5a] [FIELDDATA] New used memory 641586695 [611.8mb] from field [PostalCode] would be lar
ger than configured breaker: 622775500 [593.9mb], breaking
[2015-11-16 18:22:33,777][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [node-5a] [index_main][1], node[Kzhhh3XlRXmQpsSOEmNENw], [R], s[STARTED]:Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@43c19180] lastShard [true]
```

We understand that the real fix is to go to doc_values. This has also been coded (but not yet deployed).

**Bottom line:** Another day, another catastrophic data loss in ES.  (Good thing we use SQL Server behind this.)

**Product suggestion:** When breakers trip, perhaps the cluster status should be something other than green?  We have long monitored cluster status, and only recently learned of breakers (and have to write a fair amount of code to manage breakers).

---

Additional log info

```
[2015-11-16 18:22:33,769][WARN ][indices.breaker          ] [node-5a] [FIE
LDDATA] New used memory 641586695 [611.8mb] from field [PostalCode] would be larger than configured breaker: 622775500 [593.9mb], breaking

[2015-11-16 18:22:33,777][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [node-5a] [index_v5][1], node[Kzhhh3XlRXmQpsSOEmNENw], [R], s[STARTED]:
Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@43c19180] lastS
hard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: [index_v5_case_4905
7_2015_11_09][1]: query[filtered(+Hash:26444)->cache(_type:shipment)],from[0],si
ze[20],sort[<custom:"PostalCode": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcompara
tor.BytesRefFieldComparatorSource@3b41b3cb>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute m
ain query]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:163
...

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [PostalCode] would be larger than limit of [622775500
```

Comment: Why "catastrophic data loss"? Where are you seeing that?

Comment: @AndreiStefan From what we can tell, the data was history. 1) Our code was throwing errors when communicating w ES; 2) There were errors like the above in the ES logs (answer extended); 3) The shard stats, (shown in the OP) were seriously wrong.  I don't know everything about ES yet (but am making large and fast progress), but when the ES nodes throw errors when clients make calls, and when the logs are full of serious exceptions, we think it is game over.